# Run jQuery event handler only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to use a jquery event only once, and I have the following function:

```
function usrPlay() {
    var flag = true;
    while (flag === true) {
        $(".pincha").click(function() {
            console.log($(this).attr("value"));
            flag = false;
        });
    }
}
```

But...it seems that that makes an infinite loop, but I can`t see why. 
Any help? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But...it seems that that makes an infinite loop, but I can`t see why.

This is because you only attach event inside the loop, event handler is not executed inside loop so flag will not change to false. 
And you will probably need global `flag` var instead of local var because event handler will not be executed in scope of `usrPlay`function. Try this:

```
function usrPlay(){
  window.flag = true;
  $(".pincha").click(function(){ 
     if (window.flag === true){  
       console.log($(this).attr("value"));
       window.flag = false;
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: I marked this answer, because it not only solved my concrete problem, but made me learn why it wasn't working. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a function named by `.one()` for this.

You can use the code below for your problem.

```
$(".pincha").one( "click", function(){ 
    console.log($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

For further information about `.one()`

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: This works, thanks. But I marked the other answer because I could learn why my code wasn't working.